# post xml using curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

i'm trying to  post xml via HTTP POST method...the code works fine and displays the desired message.."Data received successfully"..problem is, on looking it up on the backend, the data is not posted on the Agenda Creative backend..where could i have messed up??thanks in advance.

```
<?php   

function sendXmlOverPost($url, $xml) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

 // For xml, change the content-type.
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // ask for results to be returned

  // Send to remote and return data to caller.
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
 }

 $postargs = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Vacancy>
 <Poster>LOGICMELON</Poster>
 <Action>Add</Action>
 <Username>agendacreative</Username>
 <Password>A12!.ndasa55</Password>
 <JobReference>AC Test 1</JobReference>
 <JobTitle>AC Test 1</JobTitle>
 <JobType>F</JobType>
 <JobHours>F</JobHours>
 <Industry>137</Industry>
 <SalaryCurrency>GBP</SalaryCurrency>
 <SalaryFrom>100.0000</SalaryFrom>
 <SalaryTo>200.0000</SalaryTo>
 <SalaryPer>D</SalaryPer>
 <SalaryBenefits>Benefits</SalaryBenefits>
 <Salary>£100 - 200 per day + Benefits</Salary>
 <JobLocation>4</JobLocation>
 <JobCountry>GB</JobCountry>
 <JobDescription>&lt;p&gt;LOGIC MELON TEST VACANCY - PLEASE DO NOT APPLY!!!&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Testing the initial integration to Agenda Creative to make sure that the template is compiled properly andt hat the fields are getting sent through correctly.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;THIS IS A LOGIC MELON TEST VACANCY - PLEASE DO NOT APPLY FOR THIS ROLE AS IT DOES NOT EXIST!!!&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;euro; - Testing Euro Sign&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;pound; - Testing Pound Sign&lt;/p&gt;</JobDescription>
<ContactName>Logic Melon Support</ContactName>
<ContactEmail>jade.sinclair.1267EC41.0@applythis.net</ContactEmail>
<ApplicationEmail>jade.sinclair.1267EC41.0@applythis.net</ApplicationEmail>
<ApplicationURL></ApplicationURL>
<WeeksToAdvertise>1</WeeksToAdvertise>
</Vacancy>
';
    $request = "http://agendacreativerecruitment.co.uk/feed.php";
    echo (sendXmlOverPost($request, $postargs));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Agenda Creative. But try something like this?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => $xml));
```

where 'xml' is the post field your xml data should be in.